# C ++ Cannot use insert to append values after a iteration on list

Tags: c++, list, insert, append

I have the following list, which prompts a user to write an student name, followed by a prompt for 3 grades in three exams obtained per student. 
I would like to append the name of the student if his grade in the first exam is > than 4.0. However when I do this in the step paso_primer_exam.insert(i) I received an Error 
   note: candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided    paso_primer_exam.insert(i);

I thought the form you can append a value after a iteration in a new list was straightforward as in Python. Does someone know how to solve the bug? 
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(){

// Crear un mapa que guarde los valores 
// de los estudiantes en la siguiente forma:
// "estudiante": [nota1, nota2, nota3]

unordered_map<string, list<float>> boletin;
string nombre;
float nota_1, nota_2, nota_3;



for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i ++){
    cout <<"Digite nombre del estudiante: " << i << endl;
    cin >> nombre; 
    cout <<"Digite las tres calificaciones: " << endl;
    cin >> nota_1 >> nota_2 >> nota_3;

    boletin.insert({nombre, {nota_1, nota_2, nota_3}});

}

// iterando e imprimiendo los elementos del 
// hashmap

list <string> paso_primer_exam;



for (auto i=boletin.begin(); i!= boletin.end(); i++){

    cout << '\n' + i -> first << endl;

    float primera_nota;
    list <float> notas = i -> second;

    primera_nota = notas.front();
    notas.begin();

    if (primera_nota >= 4.0){
        paso_primer_exam.insert(i);

    }
    for (auto it=notas.begin(); it != notas.end(); ++it){
        cout << ' ' << * it << endl;


    } 


}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at method `insert` for `std::list`
[list insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/)

there are no ways to call it with just one parameter.

maybe you want to use the `push_back` method.

P.S. And just a piece of advice for future code, try to write code in english.

Comment: correct, though there is also `std::list::push_back` with an overload that only takes an element to be added

Comment: You are right, edited, thanks.
It's just that i'm always into the `vector` choice over the `list` ;)